# Crear .htaccess y .htpasswd

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Tengo una carpeta en un servidor en el que tengo que añadir una contraseña. he investigado y he visto que hay crear un archivo `.htpasswd`. El problema es que no me funciona.

**.htaccess**

```
AuthName "Directorio privado"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/test/app/app/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd**

```
user:$apr1$Xdj0RvXW$quha1UZwlRErZvVE9qgSS/
```

El `.htaccess` lo he generado desde [aqui](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/), el usuario es: `user` y la contraseña es: `test`

No se si el problema está en la ruta que indico en el `.htaccess` o que la contraseña del `.htpasswd` no esta bien. Porque he probado en otra web que lo genera y el código era distinto.

**Respuesta del servidor**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>
        The server encountered an internal error or
        misconfiguration and was unable to complete
        your request.
    </p>
    <p>
        Please contact the server administrator,
        postmaster@adminapp.kililis.es and inform them of the time the error occurred,
        and anything you might have done that may have
        caused the error.
    </p>
    <p>
       More information about this error may be available
       in the server error log.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error da? Puedes generar un nuevo usuario/contraseña encriptados y actualizarlo en el archivo .htpasswd  Me suena más bien a un problema de rutas, pues todo parece estar bien. Nota: para ingresar debes poner el password sencillo que has puesto al momento de encriptar, no el password que aparece en el archivo `.htpasswd` Por precaución, pon una contraseña diferente al nombre de usuario, no vaya a ser eso. En cuanto a la ruta, si es un sitio web en línea, ponla como **`/home.../usuario/.htpasswd`**

Comment: No me da ningún error, simplemente no me autentica @A.Cedano ya he modificado la contraseña y no funciona

Comment: Si es un sitio web en línea, pon la ruta interna, no la url, algo como **`home/usuario/.htpasswd`** cambiando home y usuario por los datos de tu cuenta de hosting. Si es en tu propio servidor, la ruta debe ser algo así más o menos: **`/var/www/hostname/.htpasswd`** me suena a un problema de ruta.

Comment: La ruta que tengo es: `/www/test/app/app/.htpasswd` @A.Cedano

Comment: Si la ruta es correcta como dices, entonces quizá necesites poner esto en el archivo **`http.conf`** : `<Directory /path/to/the/directory/of/htaccess>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
</Directory>` Ver: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229803/5587982](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229803/5587982)

Comment: Pero, después de introducir usuario y contraseña ¿no te sale nada? ¿la pantalla queda en blanco?

Comment: Ya he añadido la respuesta del servidor @JaviPs

Comment: El archivo `http.conf` le tengo que crear en la misma carpeta donde esta el `.htaccess`???   @A.Cedano

Comment: `http.conf` es el archivo de configuraciones **general** de apache, no un archivo en la carpeta que quieres proteger. Yo insisto en que algo pasa con la ruta de tu archivo de claves. Yo lo tengo tal y como lo tienes tú, con la ruta correcta y funciona, la diferencia es que entorno es un hosting compartido (página web en línea). Te sugiero que revises [el documento oficial de Apache al respecto](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) y que sigas una de las dos vías posibles al pie de la letra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tenia era las rutas y las contraseñas.

He generado un nuevo `.htpasswd` desde [aqui](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/)

Ahora tiene esta forma:

```
User:{SHA}ZAqyuuB77cTBY/Z5p0b3q3+10fo=
User:$6ExxjO74i0C2
User:$apr1$pzmjdi6v$W0W./I2gCjOsQgJX7RVRW0
User:A donde vas?:55d045b14e09314af8b6e11ae6b65382
```

Las contraseñas están puestas en los siguientes formatos:
`sha1 Algorithm`, `crypt Algorithm`, `md5 Algorithm`, `digest Algorithm`

El archivo `.htaccess` tiene la siguiente forma:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "A donde vas?"
AuthUserFile /home/test/www/test/app/app/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Funcionar seguro que funciona, pero debo insistir en la importancia de no dejar los archivos de claves en directorios accesibles vía web por razones de seguridad. Según la página oficial de Apache: "Los archivos de contraseñas Web, como los gestionados por htpasswd, no deben estar dentro del espacio URI del servidor Web, es decir, no deben ser accesibles con una exploración"

Answer (score 1):

Consideraciones para la ruta donde debe estar el archivo. Necesitas crear un archivo de contraseñas y colocarlo en algún sitio no accesible mediante la Web. Por ejemplo, si tus documentos son servidos desde `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` deberías poner el archivo de contraseña en `/usr/local/apache/passwd`. Lo estás poniendo en el directorio `www` así que no parece muy conveniente.

Por otro lado, en el archivo de log de Apache me lanza el mensaje de error `[Mon Jun 19 13:33:15.405507 2017] [authn_file:error] [pid 6152:tid 892] (OS 3)El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.  : [client ::1:53654] AH01620: Could not open password file: C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/app/.htpasswd` así que he puesto el archivo `.htpasswd` en la ruta indicada y funciona perfectamente.

El archivo **.htaccess** que he usado:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Directorio privado"
AuthUserFile app/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: He usado tu mismo `.htaccess` pero no me funciona

Comment: El log de Apache te dará alguna pista sobre porqué no funciona.

Comment: No tyengo acceso al log de apache, uso un servidor mutualizado de un proveedor, no tengo acceso a nada del servidor. Pero muchas gracias por la ayuda